# How can i increase TR on each click using jquery clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one table with single row i want to increase one row on each click but when i click first time then its working fine but when i click second time then its increase twice.

I also want to increase count on each increment.

What i'm tried given below:-

```js
 $('.add-more-row').click(function () {
                var $repeatRow = $('.table12 tbody tr');
                $repeatRow.after($repeatRow.clone());
            });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <table class="table table-bordered table12">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th></th>
                           <th>BODY PART(S):</th>
                           <th>AREA AFFECTED:</th>
                           <th>SPECIFIC AREA:</th>
                           <th>PAIN SCALE:</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td>1</td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>

                <button class="btn btn-primary add-more-row">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add More Rows
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: _"...but when i click second time then its increase twice."_ - Because there are now two rows in the body of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $('.add-more-row').click(function () {
                var $repeatRow = $('.table12 tbody tr').last();
                $repeatRow.after($repeatRow.clone());
            });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <table class="table table-bordered table12">
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th></th>
                           <th>BODY PART(S):</th>
                           <th>AREA AFFECTED:</th>
                           <th>SPECIFIC AREA:</th>
                           <th>PAIN SCALE:</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                       <tr>
                           <td>1</td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                           <td>
                               <select class="form-control">
                                   <option>Select</option>
                                   <option>1</option>
                               </select>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>

                <button class="btn btn-primary add-more-row">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    Add More Rows
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

you run this js,

```
       $('.add-more-row').click(function () {
            var $repeatRow = $('.table12 tbody tr');
            $repeatRow.after($repeatRow.clone());
        });
```

click button first, 1 row is selected.

but after first, click button again, multi rows selected you added.

Change your js.

```
       $('.add-more-row').click(function () {
            var $repeatRow = $('.table12 tbody tr').last();
            $repeatRow.after($repeatRow.clone());
        });
```